# How can Blender render only line art?

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

I would like to create an object line art greasepencil, but having only the lines visible (not the shaded object)

The solution I found is to disable camera in ray visibility of Cycles

[image]

But it only works in rendered view and only Cycles, would there be an easier way to do that in EEVEE?

If I hide the mesh, the lineart just disappear, and if i bake the lineart it won't align to camera angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I had unknowingly incorporated the solution you were seeking for into another [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/310709/168324) that I had made.

From your words, *"only the lines visible (not the shaded object)"*, *"Cycles"*, and *"EEVEE"*, I am deducing that you want to render line art from the line art modifier without its object for any rendering engine. My solution was to create a general *Transparent Material* to hide the object for any rendering engine that we may use.

Once you have added a new material to the object, switch to `Transparent BSDF`. You can do so in the Properties tab or with the node in the Shader Editor.

[image]

In the Transparent Material's Settings, switch Blend Mode to **anything** other than `Opaque` and Shadow mode to `None`.

[image]

Upon rendering, only the line art should be visible (with your select rendering engine).

[image]

---

**Additional Notes:**

If you want to render the line art without the background, select `Transparent` within Render Properties.

[image]

If you want the object to not be visible without using Hide, an alternative is to switch the Color's Alpha to `0.000` within Viewport Display of your Transparent Material.

[image]

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Activate "Holdout" for the collection of the objects used for the line art.
[image: blender holdout]
[image: blender holdout]

Comment: This answer isn't bad but, we may not want to punch holes into our renders which can result in us having to use the compositor.

Answer (score 1):

Line Art is a GP with special modifier:

[image]

In Line Art modifier, you can see a **Bake Line Art** Button in a **baking** section. Bake your line art, then you will be able to hide meshes.

Comment: If I bake my lineart, it won't update depending on the camera, like I asked in the question.

Comment: It will. It bakes sequence of frames, not a static. But if you change something,  rebake will be required

Comment: So there isn't any other option that run the scene in viewport cycle to have only lineart visible without baking ?

Answer (score 1):

A really cheap trick, don't hate me for this. I increased the thickness of the lines and set the exposure and gamma to the full value.

You'll get an outline version of the render[image]

[image]

Comment: Havn't tested it, and yes it's more a hack than an actual option, but could be a potential solution, thanks !