# Can I use grease pencil Object line art to do science schematics?

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

I'd like to replicate the figure below with two cylinders and some rease pencil objects line art. Is there a simple way to do this?

[image: A cylinder inside another cylinder]

Here is what I have done so far (I'd rather disable the shadows inside the cylinders):
[image]

and my blend file [image] if you wish to experiment with my setup.

Answer (score 2):

I have one way for you to do this. Although, whether it is simple or not is up for interpretation.

First, let's identify what you want to create. A *schematic* or *scientific schematic* is basically known as a *Technical Drawing*. Rather than being visually illustrative, *Technical Drawings* are meant to be "constructively informative." That means viewers who "read" these drawings can build, assemble, or model whatever these drawings illustrate. Your *schematic* has two elements that you want to illustrate, a solid line and a dashed line that is better known as the *Hidden Line* within this field.

Because *Technical Drawings* are always drawn orthogonally, our first step is to make sure our drawing renders orthogonally as well. So, set the camera in your scene to `Orthographic` view from within the properties tab.

[image]

In your blend file, you added two separate grease pencil objects to create your line art. I only needed one grease pencil object with one material to hold your modifiers. For organizational purposes, I created two layers within this grease pencil object for you to handle the line art and the dashed line art.

[image]

Since your cylinders are generated through Geometry Nodes, I also consolidated your node trees into one single node tree for both of your meshes.

[image]

The *Hidden Line* is nothing more than an inferred line consisting of many smaller lines. To construct this dashed line with a grease pencil stroke, we need a lot of evenly spaced vertices built into this *Hidden Line*, so that our modifiers can generate these smaller lines. A quick fix was to increase your cylinder topology by segmenting them horizontally as many times as you segmented them vertically.

The first modifier we will add will be the `Line Art` modifier for these smaller lines. Since these lines are hidden from view, we need to select these non-visible lines by going into the `Occlusion` parameter of the `Line Art` modifier. Since there are actually two sets of faces obscuring the camera view, we will change the `Occlusion` `Level Start` to `1` and `End` to `2`. `1` is for the first set of occluded lines and `2` is for the second set of occluded lines. Make sure the grease pencil object is set to `In Front` or the `Occlusion` parameter will not be available.

The next modifier to add will be the `Dot Dashed` modifier. This modifier will convert our *Hidden Line* into a proper dashed line. I made sure this modifier would only affect our *Hidden Line* by including the layer the dashed lines are contained in. The final modifier will be another `Line Art` modifier for the solid lines. For this second `Line Art` modifier, I selected `Use Cache` so that all the line art would be baked together.

[image]

Finally, to get rid of your shadows and meshes, I created a simple Transparent shader material. I made sure to link this material to `Object` so that I wouldn't have to add it into your node tree. To render in all modes, I "disabled" `Blend Mode` and switched `Alphas` for all `Colors` to `0.000`

[image]

Hit Render and your *schematic* should be generated.

[image]

[image]
*Blender 4.0.2*

Comment: That's really nice ! (+1) Many thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. Now that I have another chance to look at this answer, I believe that we could have used just 1 mesh instead of 2 to make this diagram. All the line work was created from the modifiers anyway.

Comment: Hopefully, when geonodes works with grease pencils, that kind of tasks will be easier.